# workbench not finding package.xml in package

Tags: metadata, workbench

I have a zip file that contains package.xml in its root folder but the workbench keeps giving "No package.xml found" errors

The zip file is called trigger1.zip and it's contents are right below...

[image]

Since I'm on a mac, I've created the zip file both using the command line (zip -r -X...) and on a PC; no difference in the outcome.

Here are the workbench settings I'm using

[image]

Finally, here's the contents of my package.xml file, in case the error is a red herring

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
     <types>
        <members>DataSummaryTrigger</members>
        <name>ApexTrigger</name>  
     </types>
<version>47.0</version>
</Package>
```

What am I missing?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

well - it seems you get a different result if you zip the folder from the parent directory vs. being in the folder itself.

what I mean is

the following does not work

```
parentFolder> zip -r -X package.zip sourceFolder
```

but this does work

```
sourceFolder> zip -r -X ../package.zip *
```

go figure

I also discovered that "No package.xml found" is a catch-all error.  It'll say that when something is wrong but it doesn't know what else to say.

Answer (score 1):

To use the zip file as presented originally, uncheck the Single Package flag. If you want to use the Single Package flag, make sure you zip directly from the source directory. Either option is viable, but the Single Package flag has to match the zip structure. Note that if you uncheck the Single Package flag, it'll still work even if you only have one folder inside the zip. The flag simply tells Salesforce what to expect inside the file structure.